# Pivotal server log messages not show in Spring tools suite

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am working on Spring web MVC. I am using Spring tools suite and pivotal server. I did not found any server log messages in STS. Console only show the server startup message. I want to view all the server message, error and exceptions. Currently I am unable to view any server error messages and errors.

The console is showing the message like this-
Nov 19, 2016 1:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1312 ms
Nov 19, 2016 1:08:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5332 ms

Comment: Even I have the same issue. Anyone knows how to get complete log on console?

Answer (score 3):

i see the question is old but I came across the same issue just now and didn't want to let this one go unanswered ;)

I found an solution from [pivotal themselves](https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/202653788-Modifying-logging-configuration-for-a-Tomcat-tcServer-instance-launched-inside-SpringSource-Tool-Suite-multiple-versions-2009731-). But it has a little typo in it: The first line in the `logging.properties` is

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level= INFO
```

but should rather be just

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

This should do the trick.

And if you would still want to keep the default catalina, localhost, etc. files of the tcServer additional to the console output you can modify or copy  the `logging.properties` file found inside of your tcServer - base instance ({pivotal-tc-server-folder}/base-instance/conf/).
Here are many configurations but the one concerning the console output, which is otherwise only in the catalina-{date}.log is in the line

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
```

just change it to

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

and you'll have both: logs and console output.

Best regards,
Uwe